# How to call a modal window, get data from the database, display it in a window, save changes at the user's request

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I use flask and psycopg2 in my project.
There is a page "List of payments", the table contains a list of payments, the manager wants to see the card and the ability to edit the data by clicking on the payment.
By clicking on the name of the payment, you need to open a modal window, make a request to the database and display information about the payment in the modal window using the html window template
For me, the task is difficult, I broke it into subtasks.

1. I was able to call a modal window without html markup with actual payment data
   But I can’t load the html template, and because of this, I can’t test how to write the changed data back to the database.

My script for displaying a modal window without markup

```js
<script>
     // Function to send data to the Flask route
     function sendData() {
         var data = 'your_data_here';

         // Send an AJAX POST request to the Flask route
         $.ajax({
             url: '/get_modal_payment',
             method: 'GET',
             dataType: 'json'
             })
         .done(function(response) {
             // Create a new modal element
             var modal = $('<div id="myModal" class="modal">');

             // Create the modal content
             var modalContent = $('<div class="modal-content">');

             // Add the response data to the modal content
             modalContent.append($('<p>').text('Response: ' + response));

             // Append the modal content to the modal
             modal append(modalContent);

             // Append the modal to the body
             $('body').append(modal);

             // Display the modal
             modal show();
           })
         .fail(function() {
             // Handle any error that occurred during the Ajax request
             console.log('Error occurred');
         });

     }
</script>
```

And so I'm trying to display a modal window according to the html template

```js
<script>
     getModal() {
         $.ajax({
             url: '/open_modal',
             type: 'GET',
             success: function(response) {
                 $('#modalContent').html(response.modal_content);
                 $('#myModal').modal('show');
             };
         });
     }
</script>
```

url: '/open_modal' in Python

```py
@payment_app_bp.route('/open_modal', methods=['GET'])
def open_modal():
     modal_content = render_template('application_modal.html')
     return jsonify(modal_content=json.dumps(modal_content))
```

application_modal.html

```html
<h1>Modal Window Content</h1>
<p>This is the content of the modal window.</p>
```

The error I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\kpln\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2213, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\kpln\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2193, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\kpln\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\kpln\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\kpln\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\kpln\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\kpln\payment_app.py", line 1752, in open_modal
    modal_content = render_template('application_modal.html')
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\kpln\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 151, in render_template
    return _render(app, template, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\kpln\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 132, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\kpln\venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1301, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\kpln\venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\kpln\templates\application_modal.html", line 21, in top-level template code
    <!--&lt;!&ndash;    var data = JSON.parse('{{ data | tojson | safe }}');&ndash;&gt;-->
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\kpln\venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\filters.py", line 1688, in do_tojson
    return htmlsafe_json_dumps(value, dumps=dumps, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\kpln\venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\utils.py", line 658, in htmlsafe_json_dumps
    dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\kpln\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\json\provider.py", line 180, in dumps
    return json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 200, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 258, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\kpln\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\json\provider.py", line 120, in _default
    raise TypeError(f"Object of type {type(o).__name__} is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: Object of type Undefined is not JSON serializable
```

How to call a modal window, get data from the database, display it in a window, save changes at the user's request. It doesn't reload the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transfer in JSON format is not necessary.
To get a rendered template from the server and add it to the modal window, specify the data type you expect from the server. In this case you expect a response of type text/html, so an assignment of `html` is necessary.

```html
<script>
    function getModal() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/open_modal',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).then(data => {
            $('#myModal .modal-content').html(data);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    }
</script>
```

```py
@payment_app_bp.route('/open_modal')
def open_modal():
    # Get your data from the database and pass it on to the template.
    # ...
    return render_template('application_modal.html', **locals())
```